# Cannot get ID of entity after persist() in Hibernete multi-tenancy environment

Tags: hibernate, jax-rs

Iam trying to get the ID of an entity after calling entity manager's persist(). However, after calling persist() I do not get the ID. Also em.refresh() fails. I am using Hibernate's database multi-tenancy. It all worked okay before I introduced multi-tenancy.

This is what I have:

```
public class MyEntity{
@Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Basic(optional = false)
   @Column(name = "ID")
.....
}


@Stateless
public class ActionDAO{
......
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "project-persistence-unit")
   protected EntityManager em;

public void saveEntity(MyEntity q) {
       if (q.getId() == null) {
           em.persist(q);
           System.out.println(q.getID); // expect to get an ID here but i get 0 .
       } else {
           em.merge(q);
       }
 }
}
```

I've searched around but couldn't find a solution!

Multi-tenancy classes give below:

```
public class CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {
    @Override
    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
        String tenant = ThreadState.INSTANCE.getTenantId();
        return tenant;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
        return true;
    }
}

public class MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl extends AbstractMultiTenantConnectionProvider {
    @Override
    protected ConnectionProvider getAnyConnectionProvider() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/project1?serverTimezone=UTC");
        ds.setUsername("root");
        ds.setPassword("root");
        DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl d = new DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl();
        d.setDataSource(ds);
        d.configure(properties);
        return (ConnectionProvider) d;
    }

    @Override
    protected ConnectionProvider selectConnectionProvider(String tenantId) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        String path = MyConstants.DOCUMENT_ROOT + "/" + tenantId.toUpperCase();
        File file = new File(path + File.separator + "DATABASE.properties");
        if (file.exists()) {
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            try {
                InputStream input = new FileInputStream(path + "/DATABASE.properties");
                prop.load(input);
                DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
                ds.setUrl(prop.getProperty("URL"));
                ds.setUsername(prop.getProperty("USERNAME"));
                ds.setPassword(prop.getProperty("PASSWORD"));
                input.close();
                DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl d = new DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl();
                d.setDataSource(ds);
                d.configure(properties);
                return (ConnectionProvider) d;

            } catch (IOException | NullPointerException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;

    }

}
```

Persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="project-persistence-unit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <!--<jta-data-source>java:/PROJECT-DS</jta-data-source>-->
         <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone" value="UTC"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="250"/>
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" value="500"/> 
            <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.jndi.name" value="java:/myprojectEM"/>
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/myprojectEMF"/>
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider" value="com.myproject.auxiliary.MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl"/>
            <property name="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver" value="com.myproject.auxiliary.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl"/>
            <property name="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="DATABASE"/>
            <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Try to add @Transactional annotation on top of your saveEntity method or begin your transaction using em.getTransaction().begin() before you persist your entity and then commit your transaction using em.getTransaction().commit()

Comment: Thank you Onur. Adding @Transactional rightly throws an error ("Transaction is not accessible when using JTA with JPA-compliant transaction access enabled") because I am using JTA as my transaction type. Note that when I remove multi-tenancy I am able to get the ID. I must be missing something?

Comment: I see! Ok sorry. Actually there may be many possibilities. First of all, try to be sure that the transaction is committed. May be there's a problem with the session or entity state! May be the currentTenantIdentifier can not be resolved correctly? Just check this https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-5-multitenancy and review your configuration after you become sure that the transaction is committed!

Comment: Thanks Onur. I solved this by changing Datasource from 'DriverManagerDataSource' to 'BasicDataSource' (in my MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl).

Answer (score 0):

Update class MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl to use org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource instead of org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl